$E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ tiles all of $\mathbb{R}^d$ by specific translation iff $m(E)=1$ for lebesgue measure
We have $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ Lebesgue measurable generates a paving of $\mathbb{R}^d$ if the translated sets $(E+l) = \{l+x \text{ for } x  \in E\}$ with $ l \in \mathbb{Z}^d$ cover $\mathbb{R}^d$ without intersecting with each other.
In other words, if  we have:
$\mathbb{R}^d = \bigcup_{l \in \mathbb{Z}^d} (l+E)$
$(l_1 +  E)\cap (l_2+E) = \emptyset \text{  for }$ $l_1 \neq l_2$
then, prove that we necessarily have:
$m(E)=1$
with $m(.)$ being the Lebesgue measure
An example of that in $\mathbb{R}$ would be $E = ]0;1[ \text{ }\cup \{2\}$ :
$E+l = ]l;l+1[ \text{ } \cup \{l+2\}$
Clearly $E$ satisfies the properties and $m(E)  = 1$.
Note that the open intervals or the closed ones alone wouldn't work because either you won't get everything or intersection wouldn't be empty.
Can anyone help or give a hint?
Edit:
I was thinking of reasoning in $\mathbb{R}$ by covering a set $[0;N]$, but then I encountered this set:
$E = \bigcup \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[n + \sum \limits_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2^k};n + \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n+1} \frac{1}{2^k} \right[$
This set tiles $\mathbb{R}$ in a way that any set $[0;N]$ must need an infinite amount of translation to be paved. So any reasoning on finite covering of $[0;N] \text{ }\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$, or on Diameter as I was trying before is just thrown out the bucket.

What is the question exactly?

I want to prove the statement, that if E tiles $\mathbb{R}^d$ in this way, then $m(E)=1$

Perhaps I’m missing something but wouldn’t the following work?
First, define the unit cube $C:= [0,1)^d$. It is clear that $m(E \cap (C+l))= m((E-l) \cap C)$. Since $C$ and $E$ tile $\mathbb R^d$, we have
$$
m(E) =\sum_{l\in\mathbb Z^d} m(E\cap (C+l)) = \sum_{l\in\mathbb Z^d} m((E-l) \cap C) = m(C) =1.
$$

More generally, the same argument implies that if $\Lambda$ is a $d$-dimensional lattice in $\mathbb R^d$ and $E$ tiles $\mathbb R^d$ with respect to $\Lambda$, i.e., $\mathbb R^d = \bigcup_{l\in \Lambda} (E+l)$ and $(E+l_1)\cap(E+l_2) = \emptyset$ for any two distinct $l_1,l_2\in\Lambda$, then $m(E)$ is the volume of any unit cell (fundamental domain) of $\Lambda$.

I thought of  $\sum_{l\in\mathbb Z^d} m((E+l) \cap C) = m(C)$ but not $m(E \cap (C+l))= m((E-l) \cap C)$. Great Solution!! I was going other horrible directions lol
